# Como cambiar el lado que entra del modal overlay animacion Css JS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Tengo este código, solo necesito hacer que el modal entre por el lado derecho de la pantalla *(derecha - izquierda)* de la manera que esta lo hace al contrario

CSS

```
.overlay{    
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed; 
z-index: 1; 
left: 0;
top: 0;
background-color: #944743; 
background-color: #944743; 
overflow-x: hidden; 
transition: 1s; 
}
```

JS

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("Medium").style.width = "100%";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("Medium").style.width = "0%";
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="openNav()" class="btn btn-primary "><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Go somewhere</button>
<div id="Medium" class="overlay">

                    <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

                    <!-- Overlay content -->
                    <div class="overlay-content">
                        <h1>hola mundo</h1>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Comparte el código completo, para ver que librerías estas usando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es que la clase overlay empiece por la derecha con `left:100%` y con las animaciones de js cambiarlo, hacer que cuando lo abras tenga `left:0` y cuando lo cierres `left:100%` otra vez, aquí tienes tu ejemplo de derecha a izquierda:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("Medium").style.width = "100%";
  document.getElementById("Medium").style.left = "0";
  
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("Medium").style.width = "0%";
  document.getElementById("Medium").style.left = "100%";
}
```

```css
.overlay{    
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed; 
z-index: 1; 
left: 100%;
top: 0;
background-color: #944743; 
overflow-x: hidden; 
transition: 1s; 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openNav()" class="btn btn-primary "><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Go somewhere</button>
<div id="Medium" class="overlay">

                    <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

                    <!-- Overlay content -->
                    <div class="overlay-content">
                        <h1>hola mundo</h1>

                    </div>

                </div>
```